# routes and CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app (a tutorial) which has Articles and Comments.  An Article has_many Comments.  A Comment belongs_to an Article.  I'm having a problem deleting an Article's Comment.  Here are the files in question:

**app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
<h3>
  <%= comment.name %> &lt;<%= comment.email %>&gt; said:
<span class='actions'>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', [@article, comment], confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
</span>
</h3>
<%= comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

**CommentsController**

```
  before_filter :load_article

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.new(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @article, :notice => 'Thanks for your comment'
    else
      redirect_to @article, :alert => 'Unable to add comment'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @article, :notice => 'Comment deleted'
  end

  private
    def load_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

The problem is when I'm at address **localhost:3000/articles/1** and try to delete a comment.  Instead of being redirected to the Article show action I get this error at address **localhost:3000/articles/1/comments/3**:

```
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController
```

any help greatly appreciated,
thanks,
mike

Comment: That means the request is not sent as a `DELETE` request, which would map to the `destroy` action, but as `GET`, which maps to the `show` action. Please add the actual HTML created for your delete link, and the output of your log file that shows the HTTP request and the parameters.

Comment: Delete `link_to` works with some javascript help, so if you disabled scripts in your browser, did not include javascript files to the layout or have some js errors, the link will lead to show action instead of destroy one. Do you see "Are you sure?" confirmation after clicking the link?

Comment: Yeah, the "Are you sure?" wasn't appearing.  I changed `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` to `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` and that fixed things but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic options here, because a link in most browsers can only send a GET request.

First option is to include the java-script default files into the page

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> #this mocks a delete action by modifying the request automatically
```

Second and much preferable is to use button_to instead. First, there is a logical separation between a link to a place and a button to do something. Delete is definitely an action. Further, buttons aren't followed by spiders so nothing ever gets accidentally called.

```
<%= button_to 'delete', @comment, :method => :delete %>
```

========= EDIT FOR COMPLETENESS =======
If you are worried about the links and buttons not looking the same, an easy solution is to us [jquery/jquery_ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) to style all links and buttons exactly the same.